# Как отформатировать XML-файл при создании?

Tags: java, xml, xmlparser

Всем здравствуйте.

Вот код, который создаёт XML-файл.

```
public void createFile(List<Integer> list) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;

        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.newDocument();

            Element root = document.createElement("entries");
            document.appendChild(root);

            for (Integer value : list) {
                Element subRoot = document.createElement("entry");
                root.appendChild(subRoot);

                Element entry = document.createElement("field");
                entry.setTextContent(String.valueOf(value));
                subRoot.appendChild(entry);
            }

            StreamResult file = new StreamResult(new File("1.xml"));
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
            transformer.transform(source, file);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Получается файл с таким содержанием:

```
<entries>
<entry>
<field>1</field>
</entry>
<entry>
<field>2</field>
</entry>
<entry>
<field>3</field>
</entry>
...
</entries>
```

Как привести его к такому виду?

```
<entries>
    <entry>
        <field>1</field>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <field>2</field>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <field>3</field>
    </entry>
...
</entries>
```

Как сделать этот отступ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо включить отступы `INDENT` и настроить их величину (сколько этот отступ будет  длину, так сказать)

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
```

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей!